# Best way to dropdown a list of country in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a form where users input some information and I want to add to this form a country and I am wandering what is the best way to do this (seed data, Csv, ...) i don't want to use a gem

Comment: I'd say the best way to do it is to use a gem. Short of that, the best way would be to look how the country_select gem does it, and copy that.

Comment: if iam using a gem the country would be searchable?? i am using sunspot gem for search

Answer (score 0):

Since this is essentially static data, I wouldn't even store it into the database. I would create a PORO that had a class method that returns a 2 dimensional array (country with country abbreviation). It's just a matter of sourcing that data.

Here's a list you can use.

https://github.com/karmi/localized_country_select/blob/master/locale/en.rb

Comment: what do you mean by PORO??

Comment: A "Plain old Ruby object". Basically, just an object.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) gem.  It is very simple to use.  Just supply model and attribute as parameters:

```
country_select("user", "country")
```

Here is an example from one of my forms:

```
<%= f.fields_for (:address) do |b2| %>
     <%= b2.input :street %>
     <%= b2.input :city, :label => "City/Suburb" %>
     <%= b2.input :state %>
     <%= b2.input :post_code %>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="controls">
           <%= b2.country_select :country, ["Australia", "New Zealand"] %>
        </div>
     </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Doh, just noticed OP doesn't want to use a gem.

Comment: if iam using a gem the country would be searchable?? i am using sunspot gem for search

Comment: Yes, it just stores the country in your model normally. So for an example, in my database in the country column it says 'Australia'.

Comment: Ok thanks i have try it and i find it easy to use but still have a problem why when i select a country for example france and submit the form and go to the show page i get FR instead of France my code in the show page look like this <%= @user.country %>

Comment: It looks like they have changed that in the 2.x version.  Try it with gem 'country_select', '1.2.0' in your Gemfile.

Comment: So there is no way to get the country? those 1.2.0 version support I18n

Comment: You can get the country in the latest version using `ISO3166::Country[country_code]`